# What happens after Form.Close?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a code like

```
void onDgvRelations_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && ktlg == null)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        ktlg = new FormKatalog();
        ktlg.Show();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

The idea is to check if a form

> FormKatalog ktlg

is closed. If it's closed I have to create a new form and show it to user.
The problem is that after user close the form, variable ktlg will never be null.

How to check properly if a form was not instantiated OR was closed by user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# how check if the form is already open, and close it if it does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861602/c-sharp-how-check-if-the-form-is-already-open-and-close-it-if-it-does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom bool switch and set it in [Form.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx) Event handler

```
// on the class level
private bool isClosed = false;

void OnCellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) 
{    
   if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && (ktlg == null || this.isClosed))     
   { 
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        if (ktlg == null)
        {
           ktlg = new FormKatalog();
           ktlg.FormClosed += (s, e) => this.isClosed = true;
        }

        this.isClosed = false;
        ktlg.Show();         
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default; 
   }
}
```

Comment: ktlg is a variable, so it can not be this.isClosed

Comment: if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && (ktlg == null || this.isClosed))

Comment: Your code would throw a null reference exception, as you're assigning an event handler on `ktlg` when it is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the `ktlg` variable is a class member? Then you could do the following:

```
void onDgvRelations_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && ktlg == null)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        if (ktlg == null)
        {
            ktlg = new FormKatalog();
            ktlg.FormClosed +=  (sender, e) => ktlg = null;
            ktlg.Show();
        }
        else
            ktlg.BringToFront();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you instantiating a new form when `ktlg != null`? Also you've copypasted typo from my initial answer ;) `(**0**, e)` - zero is not right name :)

Comment: Control goes into the first `if` only when `ktlg` is `null`, so code inside `if (ktlg != null)` is unreachable.

Comment: @sll: Yes, I did a quick copy & paste. Originally I wanted the OP to assign a "real" event handler, but then I saw your lambda expression, which is far more elegant ;-)

Comment: +1 Anyway your approach is right, BTW, thanks for an NullRef Ex observation :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an "On Form Closing" event which you could use.

Its a bit cheaty but you could set a flag when the user closes the form (and revert it onFormLoad)