# Change label text on a form that is already open from another method

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to change the text of a label on a C# Winform that is already open.  The form was opened from a different method in my program so it is already open and I don't have access to the original reference of the form when it was first created.

I tried to do this in the code below, but I can not access the label on the form.  Is there a way I can change the label on a form (from another method) that is already running?

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861602/c-sharp-how-check-if-the-form-is-already-open-and-close-it-if-it-does
Form fc = Application.OpenForms["form1"];

if (fc != null)
{
     //This does not work.  I can not access the lblNewItems label.
     //The label has it's public modifier set to Public and I am able
     //to set this label successfully when I create the form originally
     //from the other method.

     fc.lblNewItems.Text = "Change text"; 
}
```

When compiling the above I get the following error:

> Error 4 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for
>   'lblNewItems' and no extension method 'lblNewItems' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can someone please tell me if this is possible to do and if so; how do I change the label on a form that is already opened from another method?

Comment: is the access modifier for that label in the the designer.cs also "public" ?

Comment: @Thousand  Yes I have the access modifier for the label set to "public".  Please read my code comment in my code above.

Comment: "This does not work." Ok, **why?** Does it not compile? Does it run but not change the text? Is there an error or exception and what is its text? Help us help you!

Comment: @verdesmarald When I compile:  Error 4 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'lblNewItems' and no extension method 'lblNewItems' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @verdesmarald Also in the VS 2010 editor it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'lblNewItems' and has the lblNewItems highlighted as red

Comment: Ah, well that's much easier to explain! You need to cast `fc` to the actual type of your `Form`. I'm guessing by the name `"form1"`, that your class is `Form1`, so: `Form1 fc = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `fc` is of type `Form`, while your label `lblNewItems` is actually on some subclass of `Form` (I'm guessing your class is `Form1` based on the question). You need to cast `fc` to the actual form type before trying to access its elements:

```
Form1 fc = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];    
if (fc != null)
{
     fc.lblNewItems.Text = "Change text"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The form was opened from a different method in my program so it is
>   already open and I don't have access to the original reference of the
>   form when it was first created.

Create a public static reference to the form in Program.cs, so you can access it from any method, just check for Null before setting the text of the label.

Comment: Is this acceptable to do (i.e. good programming behavior?  I don't create the form in Program.cs; I create it in MainForm.cs so should I create the public static reference there instead?