# How do I disable opening multiple MDI Child in VB2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a menu driven application using MDI forms. My problem is that the menu in the MDI parent will create a new child every time i clicked on it. How do i allow only one particular instance of the child to be open for a particular form but allow multiple forms from different menu to be open. For example, I would want a child from "File" to be open along with an "Edit" child. Also, is there a way to close all other forms whenever a new form is open?

Comment: Have you tried checking if the form is already opened before showing it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861602/how-to-check-if-a-windows-form-is-already-open-and-close-it-if-it-is

Comment: `is there a way to close all other forms whenever a new form is open?` ~ doesn't that defeat the purpose of MDI?

Comment: i want the menu bar to be visible throughout. Can I do that without MDI?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of that my checking the [MdiChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren.aspx) array of your main form.  That array will list all of the open MDI children on your form.

You can determine if an instance of a form is open by looping through the array and checking if a form of the type requested is already open.

To close all open forms, just loop through `MdiChildren` and call `Close` on all of the forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for an existing instance of your form through the MDIChildren collection:

```
private void form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Form2 f = this.MdiChildren.OfType<Form2>().SingleOrDefault();
  if (f == null) {
    f = new Form2();
    f.MdiParent = this;
    f.Show();
  } else {
    f.BringToFront();
  }
}
```

If you want to close any previous open form, you can also just go through the MDIChildren collection:

```
if (f == null) {
  while (this.MdiChildren.Count() > 0) {
    this.MdiChildren[0].Dispose();
  }
  // etc...
```