# How to detect when a form is closing from another form still open?

Tags: c#, forms, formclosing

I am just wondering how can I detect when a form is closing from ANOTHER FORM, Say I have my main client open another form open called sender, how would I detect when the sender form is closing from the main client form?

Comment: Very good suggestion, let me try that, thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Duplicate of [How to check if a windows form is already open, and close it if it is?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3861742/342740), you can disregard the close part of the code and focus on the rest

Comment: @Prix - It is not a duplicate -this is about the form closing.

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question then post the answer *as an answer to the question* and not as an edit to the question itself.

Comment: @Enigmativity he said when his SECONDARY form is closing not the main form so yes he can use that question to fit his needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach an event handler to the form's closing event.

This will allow you to do whatever it is you want to do when the form closes.

Answer (score 3):

You can attach, from the "ANOTHER FORM", an event handler to the `FormClosing` event

```
form.FormClosing += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    //Do your magic here
};
```

There is also a `System.Windows.Forms.Forms.Closing` event but it has been deprecated since .NET 2.0

Comment: I gave you a +1 because its code, but perhaps an explanation would go well with it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easier than with an event:

```
if (!otherForm.IsDisposed)
{
    // otherForm is still open
}
```