# After calling Close(), how to check if the form was really closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom Form class, which is reacting to the `Closing` event, like this:

```
class MyForm: Form
{
    ...
    private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( ... )
            e.Cancel = true;
    }    
    ...  
}
```

Now, somewhere else, I call `Close()` on this form:

```
 MyForm frm;
 ...
 frm.Close();
```

**Question:** After calling `Close()`, how can I find out whether the form was really closed, or if the closing was cancelled in the `Closing` Event?

The `Close()` method does not return a value, and it also does not throw an exception.

Comment: It's all of this your code?  Couldn't you just add a propery `IsClosed` and set it to true in your `FormClosing` if it closes and then check it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861602/how-to-check-if-a-windows-form-is-already-open-and-close-it-if-it-is

Comment: Subscribe to its [`FormClosed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `IsHandleCreated` property.

```
frm.Close();
if(frm.IsHandleCreated)
{
    // Closing the form was cancelled, the form is still there
}
```