# c# How to Detect Opened Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'am trying to detect opened forms in C# with this code;

```
if ((Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1) != null)
{
    Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Close();
}
```

But my form has `ShowInTaskBar = false` and my code does not work.

How can I detect opened or closed forms if the form has property `ShowInTaskBar = false`?

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861602/how-to-check-if-a-windows-form-is-already-open-and-close-it-if-it-is

Comment: if form property  is ShowInTaskBar=false; this solution is not working

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is got application level get forms can do as follows.

```
FormCollection openforms = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form form in openforms)
{
    if (form.Name == "frmsomething")
    {
        form.Close();
    }
    // Whatever you want do with individual forms in form object
}
```

Comment: thank you for quicky replay but it is not working. if form property is ShowInTaskBar=false; openforms count is 0.i changed property ShowInTaskBar=true; openforms count is 1. but this solution does not work for me

Comment: I test it , its fine even with ShowInTaskBar=false, Share more detail of your problem maybe its from somewhere else...

Comment: So maybe here is your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751554/application-openforms-count-0-always

Comment: Good work in researching the problem and discovering the duplicate. @OnurKülekci if you set the ShowInTaskBar after the creation of the form you get that bug

Comment: @Steve Thanks! Solved my problem. your comment is solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is that `ShowInTaskBar = false` causes .NET to ignore the form in the list of opened forms. You can however set the form not to show in task bar by using Windows API as described int [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16273735/732221).

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2 form
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form = new Form2();
        form.Show();
    }

private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(form != null && !form.IsDisposed){
              form.Close();
        }
    }
```