# Button click to open new form and don't open if already have active form running

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, button, click

I have a button click event which will pop up a form. How do I check if an existing form is already present before creating one and showing it?

here is my code

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        Wizard wizard = new Wizard();

        if (wizard.IsVisible)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            wizard.Show();
        }
    }
```

the code here does not work as a new pop up wizard (form) is created everytime i click on the button from another window.

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861602/how-to-check-if-a-windows-form-is-already-open-and-close-it-if-it-is?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It would be more user-friendly to disable the Button when the form is shown and re-enable it when the form is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `ShowDialog` and make it modal

Or use the reference reference to `wizard` or a `bool` flag to make the check. Make sure if you use a reference to set it `null` afterwards

```
bool isOpen;

...

public void click()
{     
    if (!isOpen)
    {
        // do something
        wizard = new Wizard();
        wizard.Closing += (sender, args) =>
                            {
                                isOpen = false;
                            };
        isOpen = true;
        wizard.Show();
    }
...
```

Or as noted in comments. Set the button Enabled property false to protect from further hits

```
Enabled = false;
```